# How do I fully clear Firefox's cache of CSS and JavaScript files?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I work on a website at my work. The issue is that if I visit the site, which uses the cached versions of the CSS and JavaScript files, and then upload an updated copy of a CSS/JavaScript file, Firefox will still use the cached version.

I can go to 'Tools->Clear Recent History' and clear the Cache of "Everything" and it still uses the cached version of the files. It will eventually updated and use the new files, but it can takes hours for this change to occur.

So, how do I completely clear Firefox's cache of these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No longer a valid solution.
/nifle

I have had good use of this Addon: [Clear Cache Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clear-cache-button/)

Comment: The link's dead!

Answer (score 22):

Another option is when refreshing the page, click Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R instead of just F5. This will refresh and overwrite any cache that Firefox has of that page. This is supported by [this](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/keyboard%20shortcuts) Mozilla web page.

Comment: I am doing this right now and it does not help. Actually, when I view css file itself - it's updated. But somehow, the html page still uses old css because I can see styles are not updated. And inspector is not picking up style of the class that my html element has.

Comment: OK. I use Cloudflare to handle my SSL certs. I went into Caching > Configuration > Developer Mode and enabled it. I think that + Ctrl-Shift-R did the trick. Edit: that was definitely it.

Comment: Now I am debugging a C# MVC application on localhost, and my js file got cached and shortcuts don't work. And I have "Disable HTTP cache when toolbox is open" checkbox checked. What is going on? Why is it so hard to uncache things?